# How do I reference the cell value within a formula string?

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am trying to create a dynamic hyperlink to a cell in the worksheet. By dynamic I mean the hyperlink would always jump to the cell in the active sheet, rather than a specific worksheet in the workbook.

I was able to find the formula for a dynamic HYPERLINK for referencing the active sheet:

[cell hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqB1K.png)
`=HYPERLINK("#D116",B37)`

Now, I am trying to make sure that the reference cell also stays dynamic, not just the link. Meaning, if I add or remove rows, I want the cell number to adjust automatically. Since the cell number is within the quotation marks, I figured I cannot do that within original **HYPERLINK** function. Hence, I am trying to figure out how to incorporate the formula from **Column C** into the **HYPERLINK** function.

[the value I need to incorporate in the HYPERLINK function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf3su.png)
`=CHAR(34)&"#D"&ROW($A$116)&CHAR(34)`

`=HYPERLINK("&C37&",B37)` does not work.

Is it possible? If not, is there another way of doing so? VBA, perhaps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",D116),B37)
```